# IE does not support arrow(=>)

Tags: javascript, html, web, foreach, arrow-functions

this is my code:

```js
 function LoadDate() {
    document.querySelectorAll('[display-date]').forEach(el => el.innerHTML = getTheDate());
    }
```

It is not working on IE because of this arrow (el => ) as I understand from my last question .. how can I convert it to be supported in all browsers?

Thanks for your time ^_^

Comment: You need some JavaScript compiler. The most used is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/).

Comment: Or you could just use a normal non-arrow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function LoadDate() {
    var displayDates = document.querySelectorAll('[display-date]');
    for (var i = 0; i < displayDates.length; i++) {
       displayDates[i].innerHTML = getTheDate()
    }
 }
```